# linq: grandparent - parent - children query

Tags: linq, entity-framework

I have an entity model and I've been looking to write a linq query that returns counts of children and parents for each grandparent.

**I need to output 3 columns: Name of Grandparent | Count of Children | Count of Grandchildren**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     using (FamilyModel.TheConn myEntities = new FamilyModel.TheConn())
     {
          int TheUserID = 13; // will change later

          var myOutput = from gparents in myEntities.GrandParents
                     where gparents.UserID == TheUserID
                     select gparent.Name, // here's what's missing: the counts

          GridView1.DataSource = myOutput;
          GridView1.DataBind();

     }
}
```

I've been struggling with SelectMany, Groupby, joins.... I just don't get the result I need for this seemingly simple query.
Any input would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I think a bit more information about the schema would help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var myOutput = from gparent in myEntities.GrandParents
               where gparent.UserID == TheUserID
               select new GrandParentViewModel
               {
                   Name = gparent.Name,
                   ChildrenCount = gparent.Children.Count(),
                   GrandChildrenCount = gparent.Children.SelectMany(c => c.GrandChildren).Count()
               };
```

That's assuming your `Child` entity has navigational property `GrandChildren` (actually the name `Children` world make more sense here - children of children = grandchildren).

In this case we project onto a `GrandParentViewModel`:

```
public class GrandParentViewModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int ChildrenCount { get; set; }
    public int GrandChildrenCount { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: The result is unexpected: 1) Name shows "it" (the Intellisense doesn't show the field GparentName), 2) the columns show the same grand total of children and grandchildren in the database and there are 6 rows showing (1 row per grandprent). It should show the name and the count for each grandparent instead of the entire total of children and grandchildren. This is weird.

Comment: There were a few typos in the code - I edited them out. Should start with 'from gparent' instead of 'from gparents'. Did you have a variable `gparent` defined anywhere before by chance? Secondly, the `myOutput` variable is a query - if you want the results for one grandparent (the one with `TheUserId`), you need to call `myOutput.FirstOrDefault()`. If you want to retrieve a list of grandparents, call `myOutput.ToList()`.

Comment: OH MY GOD IT WORKS!!!!! Thank you sooooo much. I've been struggling with these few lines of code for the last 3 days since I'm new to linq. Your answer will stay in the net for a while because it really solves a problem that I'm sure many struggle with until they figure it out. Thank you very much!!